# Does it exists a PHP function that creates key => value bindings in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, setter

Is there a function like this so I can do:

```
populate_array($array, 'key', $value)
```

instead of doing:

```
$array['key'] = $value;
```

?

I'm asking this because I want to circumvent the "Indirect modification of overloaded property" error that occurs when you use magic getter and setter and you want to set an array attribute:

```
class MyClass
{
    private $string;
    private $array;

    public function __set($attribute, $value)
    {
        $this->$attribute = $value;
    }

    public function __get($attribute)
    {
        if (isset($attribute))
        {
            return $this->$attribute;
        }
    }
}

$obg = new MyClass();

$obg->string = 'Hey it works!';
$obg->array = ['This works', 'too!'];
$obg->array['key'] = 'This will throw `Indirect modification of overloaded property MyClass::$array has no effect`';
```

Comment: Solution: Write a custom function. `I want to circumvent the "Indirect modification of overloaded property" error ...` Can you explain?

Comment: Do you want something like $key => $value ?

Comment: Well, `$array` is private. Make it public if you wish to be able to modify it outside the class like that

Comment: @LucasMalor I'm with One_Trick_Pony

Comment: @OneTrickPony: even if you render it public the 'Indirect modification' error occurs. I think this is because __get is invoked instead.

Comment: `__get` would never be called if the prorperty is declared and public (it looks like you don't even need `__get`/`__set` magic)

Comment: @OneTrickPony: sorry, my fault. Anyway this way I'll have no encapsulation. See also this comment of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468006/does-it-exists-a-php-function-that-creates-key-value-bindings-in-an-array#comment25383390_17468187

Comment: Why don't you post your real code? Your current getter and setter mimic PHP's default behavior and this makes them redunant

Comment: @OneTrickPony: I can't post my real code. Why is this redundant? I'm simply using magical getter and setter to do encapsulation instead of writing one getter and one setter for any attribute.

Comment: You are only "encapsulating" declared properties. If I do `$obg->foo = 42`, your setter will turn it into a public property, so next time I request it `__get` won't be invoked. It's redundant because your getter checks if a property exists and returns it, your setter simply sets a (public) property with the requested value. This is what PHP does by default

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom one.

```
function setArrayValue(&$array, $key, $value)
{
    $array[$key] = $value;
}
```

As per your second update -

```
class MyClass
{
    private $arr1;
    private $arr2;

    public function setArrayValue($arrayName, $key, $value)
    {
        $this->$arrayName[$key] = $value;
    }
}

$obg = new MyClass();
$obg->setArrayValue('arr1', 2, 3);
$obg->setArrayValue('arr3', 6, 9);
```

There could be many methods, it depends on your need.

Comment: Mmmmmhhh... no :D please read the second part of my question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468006/does-it-exists-a-php-function-that-creates-key-value-bindings-in-an-array#comment25383390_17468187

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to create a public method to modify an internal variable inside the class. This is the way it should be done. ([principle of encapsulation](http://wshell.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/encapsulation-in-php/))

```
class MyClass
{
    private $string;
    private $array;

    public function setArrayAtKey($key, $value){
        $this->array[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

And calling it like:

```
$obg = new MyClass();
$obg->setArrayAtKey('key', 'this works');
```

Comment: This will not work for any array, but only with $array (and the same it's for @Jim). I would have a sort of magic method for any array.

Comment: Lucas surely that won't matter though as $array is internal to the class anyway its not an external array.

Comment: @LucasMalor of course, you can create a generic function if you have more than one array in your class and prefer to reuse a method. That's up to you. I just created this setter for you array. It could have better be named according to the array function. (`setAge`, for example, or `setSiblings`). Basically you don't want to name a variable `array` in any case.

Comment: "you can create a generic function": well, this will not answer my question.

Comment: @LucasMalor you should open a new question for that. You didn't specify this requirement in your question. Anyway, I believe you should not create a generic function for it...

Answer (score 1):

I would add a method to your class:

```
class MyClass
{
    private $string;
    private $array;
/* snip */

    public function addItem($key, $value){
        $this->array[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

This will allow you to set from outside the class:

```
$obg = new MyClass();
$obg->addItem('someKey','someValue');//Assumes array already exists.
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be the correct code in your case:

```
class MyClass
{

}

$obg = new MyClass();

$obg->string = 'Hey it works!';
$obg->array = ['This works', 'too!'];
$obg->array['key'] = 'This will NOT throw `Indirect modification...';
```

But if you have **good reasons** to use magic `__get` and `__set` with private properties, then make your `array` property an object that implements [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php), or just use the `ArrayObject` class:

```
$obg->array = new ArrayObject(['This works', 'too!']);
$obg->array['key'] = 'This will NOT throw `Indirect modification...';
```

Comment: It does not work :( I added `$this->array = new ArrayObject();` to the constructor, but the error occurs anyway. And using `offsetSet()` gives me `Call to a member function offsetSet() on a non-object`, because __get is invoked.

Comment: Emh... I forgot to remove `$obg->array = ['This works', 'too!']` :-P Anyway it doesn't work because it bypass the __set method, so no encapsulation.

Comment: Not really, set logic for the `ArrayObject` is handled by `offsetSet()`. If you create your own `ArrayAccess` class you can override that method

Comment: Well, I appreciate your answer and I vote it up, but it's a bit overcomplicated :)